# Can I extract the x scale from a DC chart that has elasticX(true)?

Tags: dc.js

I'd like to add some squares to a DC bubbleChart, using D3 and non-crossfiltered data. (There is so much data that a proper DC solution here, such as a scatter plot with different series, won't work.) I'd like to use the scale used by the DC chart to position the squares. The user can change series via dropdowns, so the scale is dynamic.

The bubbleChart uses .elasticX(true) and .elasticY(true), so the scales I pass in via .x and .y are not accurate and in fact I just supply dummy scales with .domain([0,100]).

It is possible to extract the scale being used by the bubbleChart? I've tried console.log(bubbleChart); and had a look through all the properties, but the relevant ones just give me a function. How do I access the scale? Or, failing that, how do I access the min and max in use by the axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general most methods in dc.js charts are combined getter / setters. So you can use

```
chart.x()
```

to retrieve the X scale, and thus

```
chart.x().domain()
```

to retrieve the calculated bounds.

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#x